# MS Project integration with TFS is missing fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, team-foundation-server, microsoft-project

I regularly use the TEAM integration with MS Office products.

However there is a discrepancy in terms of the fields available to either Excel or Project

Excel for example will happily return you Original Estimate and Effort as part of a query which includes those two standard fields

On Project, which seems to have a different name for a number of fields to either that of Excel or the web ui, simply doesn't seem to have an equivalent for either of them

Please can anyone tell me what I might be missing? This is Project 2013, incidentally

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the mappings have to be done in config on the server, in quite a convaluted fashion. There is an XML file which can be exported then edited and only imported back again if you have Office installed on the TFS server as there are binaries it needs to do this. Pretty awful experience but we will give it a go and see if it resolves it.